# Iterate a Python script over files, with wildcard expansion, and passing through args

Tags: python, loops, wildcard, glob, execfile

I have some scripts which do some processing on a file. Typically they accept the file as their first command-line argument, and other arguments after that.

I want to write a master script which accepts the name of the script to run, a wildcard specifying the target files (a-la `glob`), and possibly arguments to pass to the input script. The master script shall iterate over the files, and run the input script with the additional arguments.

Note that the input scripts are legacy, and possibly do not contain the usual `if __name__ == "__main__":` line at the end. They may also access `sys.argv`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: A shell script, and this smells like a use case for [`xargs`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs).

Answer (score 0):

[`import glob`](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html)

Should get you started,

I would also subprocess the scripts and pass them arguments.

Comment: check on the glob. How do I use subprocess in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this. (very rough, but you get the idea)

```
import os
import sys

def callScripts(wildcard, arguments):
    # convert a list ["hello", "world"] to a space delimited "hello world"
    arguments = " ".join(arguments)
    for file in os.listdir(".")
    # feel free to replace with regex or w/e
    if file.endswith(wildcard)
        # system shell call
        os.system("python " + file + " " + arguments)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    wildcard = sys.argv[1]
    arguments = sys.argv[2:]
    callScripts(wildcard, arguments)
```

Comment: Edit: I think the shell script is the way to go. But you can use this if you need cross platform, more readability, more processing power than shell scripts provide.

Comment: os.system is a bad way to do this.

Comment: @JakobBowyer why is os.system a bad way, and what's better?